# e.Tag DelegateCommand Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, delegatecommand

i have a little problem and find no way how to fix it. I create a Button with a Commandbinding. This Button calls a DelegateCommand, but i need the "e.Tag" of this button and DelegateCommand just return "null". So do any of you know a way to solve this?
ps. ImgSource ist bound to an Imagesource so i need this way to change it at runtime.
The Button itself works..

```
public Datenbank datab = new Datenbank();
Binding b = new Binding("GetValue");
b.Source = datab;
champbtn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, b);
champbtn.Tag = path;

public class Datenbank : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _sourcep;
    public string ImgSource
    {
        get { return _sourcep; }

        set
        {
            _sourcep = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImgSource");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public Datenbank()
    {
        GetValue = new DelegateCommand(Set);
    }

    public void Set(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Button src = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
        string taged = src.Tag.ToString();
        ImgSource = taged;
        //This causes an error because e == null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that [`e.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx) is necessary? If you handle the event on the same control that raises it you could cast the sender instead.